# Nextjs with axios, error 419 on post request to laravel api route

Tags: laravel, axios, next.js

There's a lot solution here for this question, and it's just simply specifying a CSRF token. But I'm using Laravel as an API, and on API routes it's not protected by CSRF.

Here's my axios request:

```
axios.post(
    `${API_URL}/v1/admin/login`,
    {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    },
    {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "x-requested-with": "XmlHttpRequest",
      },
    }
  );
```

This is to an API route, not a web route so CSRF token shouldn't be the issue. This works fine on Postman.

Though I want to clarify that the error message is "CSRF token mismatch.", but I have built several APIs before and this is the first time I've encountered this issue. This is my first time using nextjs.

Comment: Which middleware are you applying on your `v1` group in RouteServiceProvider.php Also check http Kernel.php if you're actually not using `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware

Comment: @Salam there's no middleware, since it's a login route it should be publicly accessible. For `VerifyCsrfToken`, yes I have already verified this. I ended up adding `api/*` to `$except` under the `VerifyCsrfToken` class which fixed the problem. But it's still weird, this shouldn't be an issue because it's an API route, and API routes do not use this middleware. I'm using Laravel 8